# Relationship between parabolas and hyperbolas

Tags: calculus, integration, conic-sections

So I was a bit bored earlier today and decided I'd work some problems with projectiles.

I was kind of curious to see what solving for the arc length of a projectile launched horizontally would be like. Hence, I came up with a pretty general parametrisation:

$$\vec r(t)=\langle bt,-at^2+c\rangle$$

Decided my interval would be from its maximum until its height was zero, which gave the following bounds:

$$t\in\left[0,\sqrt\frac{c}{a}\right]$$

Last thing to do was compute some derivatives and set up a rectification integral.

$$x'=b$$

$$y'=-2a$$

Which gave me the following equation for arc length:

$$\int_0^{\sqrt\frac{c}{a}}\sqrt{b^2+4a^2t}\;dt$$

I'd recently been working on problems involving the area of hyperbolic cross sections and thought it was a bit strange that the length of one conic section (parabola) was equivalent to the area under another (hyperbola). Due to the relations between conics, I figured it might be more than just coincidence.

Is there any particular reason that the arclength of a parabola evaluates to the area of a hyperbola?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are suggesting that given parameters $a,b$ and a range of $x$, that the area under the hyperbola is **equal** to the arc length of the parabola. Clearly, as we shall see below, they are structurally similar, but by no means equal under the assumptions stated above. I'm going to consider a very simple case to illustrate the point. With reference to the figure below,

$$
y_h^2=1+x^2\\
y_p=1-x^2\\
x\in[-1,1]
$$

Thus,

$$
A_h=\int_{-1}^{1}y_h~dx=\int_{-1}^{1}\sqrt{1+x^2}~dx=\sqrt{2}+\sinh^{-1}(1)\\
s_p=\int_{-1}^{1}\sqrt{1+y'^2}~dx=\int_{-1}^{1}\sqrt{1+4x^2}~dx=\sqrt{5}+\frac{\sinh^{-1}(2)}{2}
$$

Now, given free reign over the parameters $a,b$ I'm sure you could always find a case where the area under the hyperbola is equal to the arc length of the parabola. For example, in the case given above, just change $y_p$ to

$$y_p=1-\frac{x^2}{2}$$

to achieve the desired result.
[image: Parabola & Hyperbola]

Comment: I think you've misunderstood my question. I was trying to see if there's any deeper reason that the area bound by some hyperbola that arises in a rectification integrand is what we use to evaluate the arc length of a parabola.

Comment: Well, I still think you are looking at something that's just a coincidence. If you are looking for a relation between a parabola, say $y_p=a+bx^2$ and a hyperbola, say $y_h^2=a+bx^2$ you can look to a special case of the centroid that I developed some time time ago. To wit, the centroid of said hyperbola is equal to the area of the parabola divided by twice the area of the hyperbola, i.e., $y_{hc}=A_p/(2A_h)$.

Comment: Okay, that's more along the lines of what I was looking for.  The main thing I think you missed in your answer is that in the OP, the formula I gave clearly showed a discrepancy in length between conjugate and transverse axes (by a factor of 2), but your hyperbolic integral assumed they were the same length which is the reason you said they weren't equivalent. Regardless I appreciate the post